# Is going to sleep at 10PM healthier than at 12AM?

Tags: sleep

I have heard often that the hours you sleep before 12 AM are extra important, so for example it is better to sleep from 22:00 until 6:00 than to sleep from 0:00 until 8:00. In order to specify the question, just compare sleeping from 10PM to sleeping from 12AM.
What is the scientific consensus on this?

[Here](https://medium.com/basicdrop/each-hour-of-sleep-before-midnight-is-worth-two-73da525ee86a) is an example of a source.

I have also found an academic article, which researches the correlation between sleeping onset time and cardiovascular disease; [here](https://academic.oup.com/ehjdh/article/2/4/658/6423198?login=true) is a link.

Comment: I think you mean "12am", 12pm is noon.

Comment: Thanks @quant, I changed it

Comment: Note that the study you cited says going to sleep **before** 10:00 pm also increases the incidence of cardiovascular disease, so the blogger's blanket statement that before midnight is healthier may be wrong.

Comment: Good point, Carey Gregory. I will modify the question